# Order by in Sub-query

Tags: oracle

I want to see the details of employee who has minimum salary from Employees table without using min() function .For that I have written code as below

```
SELECT *
FROM Employees 
WHERE SALARY IN (SELECT SALARY
                 FROM Employees
                 order by salary)
AND ROWNUM=1
```

Here it's showing the error

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
>   00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 5 Column: 18

so what's the error there....????

I was reading from this website

> http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp   See syntax of oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do select from select that will be already sorted and take the first row.

```
 select * from
    ( SELECT *
                     FROM Employees
                     order by salary ) A 
    where rownum = 1
```

You are not able to do it in just one select as rownum will be executed before order by. That's why we need wrapp it in additional SELECT.

Answer (score 1):

ORDER BY is not supported in IN CLAUSE because it doesn't make any sense. You filter rows from a set and it doesn't matter in which order you filter them. You should order the resulting rows and then pick the first one (ROWNUM = 1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LIMIT operator as well.

```
    SELECT *
    FROM Employee 
    WHERE salary IN (SELECT salary
             FROM Employee
             order by salary)
    LIMIT 1
```

I have used http://sqlfiddle.com/ to verify this. You can verify this here:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d73aa3/3/0

Here are the table creation and bootstrapping statements.

```
    CREATE TABLE Employee
    (
    name varchar(50),
    salary double
    );

    insert into Employee values('bob', 80000.00);
    insert into Employee values('john', 100000.00);
```

Comment: There is no LIMIT in Oracle. And it doesn't work. Just random salary is selected.

Comment: Since not much info was mentioned regarding the platform, i assumed it to be mysql.  And yes, looking at the error code would have been helpful in figuring that out :)

Comment: @deepakmarathe, the error code "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis" should have been a big clue that it was not mysql :)